# Why i18n with Node.js keeps deleting and replacing my languages variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, internationalization

I am using i18n with Node.js to manage the languages of a site with 3 languages. But sometimes my home page (or any other page) refuses to load as if the server isn't running, then when I refresh the page it loads but with ALL the variables in the concerned language local file deleted and replaced only by their names only (and their names as values too). This is how the variables become:

```
{
    "helpLocalCos_L": "helpLocalCos_L",
    "signup_L": "signup_L",
    "loginToProfile_L": "loginToProfile_L",
    "whyNewHead_L": "whyNewHead_L",
    "headline_L": "headline_L",
    "atNewWeMatch_L": "atNewWeMatch_L",
    "byDoingWork_L": "byDoingWork_L",
    "workExperience_L": "workExperience_L",
    "gather_L": "gather_L",
    "references_L": "references_L",
    "andGetTo_L": "andGetTo_L",
    "dutchLanguageAnd_L": "dutchLanguageAnd_L",
    "quicker_L": "quicker_L",
    "switchLanguages_L": "switchLanguages_L"
}
```

This is given that I DO have all these variables and more variables written in the same file first place every time this happens.

I have a back up to get back my variables again, but this keeps repeating. Any idea why and how I can turn around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Never mind please! 
I figured out that my JSON had a semicolon missing, which renders it invalid and makes i18n replace it. My bad xD

Comment: it just happened to me. Thanks